# Touching a Stepson

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, negia, zivug-sheini

As an orthodox Jew, I married another orthodox Jew. This is a second marriage and he has a son. Am I allowed to touch the boy, as his stepmother, after he reaches the age of 9?

Comment: Debra, this sounds like a question you need to ask your rabbi. See the sidebar - Mi Yodeya does not offer practical advice regarding halacha. Please feel free to edit your question into a generalized inquiry. Otherwise, we need to close this.

Comment: Since the details need to be explained by someone who knows you and your family, as well is an expert in the relevant halachos, you should consult a rav.

Comment: Debra, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! Unfortunately it got closed as MY thinks you are better served by a rav for very personal questions. But don't let that discourage you from continuing to learn with us. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please also consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: And by the way a question phrased as "What are the rules of negia as it relates to stepsons or stepdaughters" would have much more chances of being answered. You can [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/69871/edit) your question if you wish. You might also want to broaden it to the issue of *yichud* (being alone with the boy) which I think will be as much, if not more, delicate

Answer (score 1):

The question I've heard more often is an adopted child, and I'd *assume* the theory would be the same. Lo and behold, in that case some rabbis say yes and some say no.

[Here's an mp3 from Rabbi Dovid Gottlieb](https://www.shaalvim.org/yeshiva/torah/view.asp?id=661) addressing the question in cases of adoption.

I hope your blended family has much success and happiness.