# Could there be a Halachik issue with using a DNA kit such as 23andMe?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, genealogy, contemporary-halacha

Besides learning fun facts about one's DNA and ancestry, there's a lot of good that can come out of using one. For example: people of Ashkenazi Jewish descent can learn if they're predisposed to BRCA1 and BRCA2 genes and thus at a higher risk for breast or ovarian cancer.

But it's a step further than Dor Yesharim or NYU testing, since those just primarily report if one's a carrier for a disease and don't analyze one's family genetics.

Was wondering if there could be any Halachik issues with using a service like 23 And Me? Potential issues could be:

- **Main problem I thought of**: if someone were to find out they're actually a *mamzer*. This is definitely not something we'd want someone to know since we try to be very lenient with *safeik mamzer*.
- finding out one is adopted (parents never told them) and could be a problem of *bitul of kibbud av v'em* (either they never wanted that person to know, or said person may not have been properly doing *bitul of kibbud av v'em*)
- If a child finds out they're adopted perhaps there could now be a concern of *yichud* with a parent of the opposite gender.

Perhaps we could suggest to follow *rov*- namely that majority of people won't find this out-  or that the good outweighs the potential bad.

To sum up:

1) can anyone think of additional problems that could arise from using a DNA kit?

2) reason(s) why we may be allowed to use them?

Comment: Is there a problem of Yichud when the child is adopted?

Comment: As DNA cannot be used to determine whether someone is Jewish or not, it cannot be used to disprove someone being Jewish. I'd think it would be the same way for mamzerut; you can't prove it with DNA because we don't use DNA in halacha. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9938/dna-and-jewish-law?rq=1

Comment: @ezra I think some raise the question, not sure if that's how we pasken- see: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84150/what-are-the-rules-of-negia-as-it-relates-to-stepsons-or-stepdaughters/84153#84153

Comment: @ezra actually that link lists multiple opinions on the matter

Comment: Stupid questions:  what does mamzer DNA look like?  Can it show signs of possible valid conversions?

Comment: @Gary DNA can connect you with your parents. If your DNA doesn't match with your "dad", then well, you're not his kid.

Comment: I've always heard it as the existence of consumer DNA tests being a good thing for adoption.  Since you can be certain that your adopted child is not going to marry a forbidden relative by accident.  (Open adoption is also a wonderful thing, but not part of this question.)

Comment: I think you shouldn't include answers in the Q. You can post them as your own answer or list them in comments.

Comment: Potential mamzerut could be proven but only with comparative DNA samples from both the mother and father to contrast against the child. It would show definite parentage. Concerning the yichud & shiddach issues, it’s a real concern, but only in relation to knowing who your actual blood relatives are. This could not be determined by any individual test. I don’t follow your kibbud Av v’Em question.

Comment: Yichud applys whether the child care is aware or not, except possibly in the far-fetched case where the adults are also not aware (baby swap for a plausible but unlikely mechanism)

Answer (score 1):

> Main problem I thought of: if someone were to find out they're
> actually a mamzer. This is definitely not something we'd want someone
> to know since we try to be very lenient with safeik mamzer.

These DNA kits only guess where you came from, they won't be able to tell you who your parents are.

> finding out one is adopted (parents never told them) and could be a
> problem of bitul of kibbud av v'em (either they never wanted that
> person to know, or said person may not have been properly doing bitul
> of kibbud av v'em)

Again, same as above.

> If a child finds out they're adopted perhaps there could now be a
> concern of yichud with a parent of the opposite gender.

Same as 1 and 2. Though if one was to find out they are a mamzer or adopted, even if it may be upsetting and create halachic complications, it wouldn't be assur - aderaba, its good we found out.

As an aside, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Isa5c1p6aC0) is an excellent video on these kits showing why they are kind of a scam.

Comment: I understand that its possible to see who is a very close relative, such as the parent or a sibling/half-sibling, and the genetic distance between them can be identified.

Comment: @IsraelReader Right. The tests he was referring to can't, but I also tried to adress the more advanced tests in the 3rd part.